# Repeat keras LSTM output of all hidden states

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

**Data:**

Macro time-series with shape = (T, M)    #same for all firms
Micro time-series with shape = (T, N, K) #firm-specific data

Where T is time-dimension in months, M the number of macro features, N the number of firms and K the number of micro features such as P/E ratio etc.

**Task: use LSTM output, repeat it N times and concatenate with micro-data**

I want to use the output of the LSTM, namely all (here H=4) hidden-states for all t in T for all firms, thus setting `return_sequences=True`, and repeat them N times in order to concatenate them with my micro-data, i.e. get new data with `shape = (T, N, K+H)`

This new data will then be reshaped to `(T*N, K+H)` and fed into a feed-forward neural network with a custom loss-function that applies to both neural nets and can by construction only be computed at time T, thus having batch-size=1!.

I have tried this the following way, but it doesn't work because of the dims:

```
from keras.layers import concatenate, Input, LSTM, RepeatVector
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from keras.models        import Model

in_macro        = Input(shape = (T, M),         name = 'macro_input')
in_micro        = Input(shape = (T, N, K),      name = 'micro_input')

lstm            = LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)(in_macro)
rep             = RepeatVector(N)(lstm)
conc            = concatenate([in_micro, rep])
model           = Model(inputs=[in_micro,in_macro], outputs=conc)

plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer repeat_vector_1: expected ndim=2, found ndim=3
```

Is there an efficient way to reach this goal, maybe even without the need to repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using `Lambda` layers and stack:

```
from keras.layers import concatenate, Input, LSTM
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as k

in_macro = Input(shape=(T, M), name='macro_input')
in_micro = Input(shape=(T, N, K), name='micro_input')

lstm = LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)(in_macro)
stack = Lambda(lambda x: k.stack(N*[x], axis=2))(lstm)
conc = concatenate([in_micro, stack])
model = Model(inputs=[in_micro,in_macro], outputs=conc)

plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

[image]